# Concat multi-index data based on inner level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe of the form below():

```
key  nm    c0    c1   c2   c3  
bar one -0.42  0.56  0.27 -1.08
    two -0.67  0.11 -1.47  0.52
baz one  0.40  0.57 -1.71 -1.03
    two -0.37 -1.15 -1.34  0.84
```

I want to concatenate the numbers in the df based on the inner level index i.e. **nm** separated by \n (assuming the numbers are represented as strings) and get rid of that level **nm** ;like this below:

```
key      c0                 c1           c2            c3  
bar  -0.42\n-0.67    0.56\n0.11     0.27\n-1.47   -1.08\n0.52
baz   0.40\n-0.37    0.57\n-1.15    -1.71\n-1.34  -1.03\n0.84
```

Please guide on how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on "key" and join with "\n". NB. You first need to cast your data as string:

```
df.astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg('\n'.join)
```

output:

```
               c0           c1            c2           c3
key                                                      
bar  -0.42\n-0.67   0.56\n0.11   0.27\n-1.47  -1.08\n0.52
baz    0.4\n-0.37  0.57\n-1.15  -1.71\n-1.34  -1.03\n0.84
```